# RSS feed - get specific item from external feed

Tags: rss, feed

I am trying to figure out the best way to do this with Wordpress. I want to show a feed of news items on my site - the items are pulled from an external RSS feed. If an item is clicked, I want to show the contents of that specific item on a page within my own site.

Looking at the contents of the external feed I am accessing, the unique identifier for each news item is stored in the query string of the link for that story, so I'm not really sure how I can use this to achieve what I want. Does anyone have any ideas at all? Thanks for any help

Comment: Do you want to have a page/post for each item within the site or just display it from the parent site/feed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Displaying feeds usually links out of your site to the rest of the original content. You will have to use feeds that display all the content (or enough to show on your own pages) and then pass that information to a page using a template that can receive and display it. An alternative is to just pass some unique identifyer to your 'content' page and then filter the feed to just show the item matching the identifyer i.e. link url would be unique. - this is all considering leaving the original content where it is: you can automatically post RSS content to your own site using a plugin like feedwordpress. This will syndicate and allow many options to display the content. Its probably the best option.